# Как отменить позиционирование у нижестоящих блоков?

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

я задал одному блоку позиционирование, а нижние блоки заходят под него, как мне быстро и легко прижать нижние блоки к низу.

Вот код:

```css
.property-help {
  background: #f7f7f7;
  position: relative;
}

.property-help__box {
  width: 1030px;
  background: #fff;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 23px;
  padding: 40px 50px 85px 50px;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 10px #ccc;
  position: absolute;
  top: -80px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -515px;
  z-index: 10;
}
```

```html
<section id="property-help" class="property-help">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="property-help__box">
      <p class="property-help__top-text">
        После того, как решены юридические вопросы с видом на жительство в Болгарии, главной задачей становится
        <span>найти новый дом или квартиру и организовать перевоз вещей</span>
      </p>
      <ul class="property-help__list">
        <li class="property-help__item">
          Мы подберем лучшие варианты для Вашей новой жизни и подходящие по ценовой категории - будь то квартира-студия для молодой пары, или роскошный дом на побережье для большой семьи.
        </li>
        <li class="property-help__item">
          При переезде в другую страну всегда возникает вопрос - как перевозить все свои вещи? Мы готовы Вам помочь в перевозке личных вещей из РФ в Болгарию. Большой опыт в перевозке вещей поможет избежать лишних затрат и выбрать только надежные и аккуратные транспортные
          компании, что гарантирует сохранность Вашего имущества.
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: а зачем Вы тогда задаёте блоку абсолютное позиционирование, если не хотите, чтобы остальные заползли под него? в этом и смысл абсолютного позиционирования: элемент выпадает из потока, и нижние занимают его место (в данном случае заползают под)

Comment: Мне нужно этот блок property-help__box приподнять вверх с помощью отрицательного маржина, а нижние чтоб были прижаты к низу

Comment: для этого существует position: relative

Comment: Спасибо, все получилось